# Segmentation Fault: 11 in C Reading from External Text-file

Tags: c

I've come across a rather annoying problem with my program. The program is made out of 3 different functions where exercise 2 and 3 are working as they should, however, exercise 1 keeps giving me a segmentation fault: 11 - I have no idea why. Can anyone address the issue and explain why it happens? I'll be grateful for any help provided!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE 200 /* MAX NO. OF CHARACTERS FROM THE WHOLE FILE */
#define MAX_NAME 10  /* MAX NO. OF CHARACTERS OF WEEKDAg, HOME- AND GUEST TEAM  */

/* STRUCTURES */
typedef struct
{
    char weekday[MAX_NAME];
    char date[MAX_NAME];
    char the_time[MAX_NAME];
    char team_home[MAX_NAME];
    char team_guest[MAX_NAME];
    char spectators1[MAX_NAME];
    char spectators2[MAX_NAME];
    int goal_home;
    int goal_guests;
    int tilskuere;
    int the_score;
} games;

/* PROTOTYPES */
int main_print();
int main_interactive();
int read_file(games *game);
int tilskuertal(games *game, int num_matches);
void uafgjorte_kampe_med_antal_maal(char *team, int goal, games *game, int num_matches);
void AAB_game(games *game, games *game_with_AAB, int num_matches);
int comparing(const void *a, const void *b);

/* MAIN FUNCTION */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "--print") == 0)
    return main_print();
  else
    return main_interactive();
}

/* PRINT WITH " --PRINT " */
int main_print()
{
    games game[MAX_LINE];
    games game_with_AAB[MAX_LINE];

    int num_matches = read_file(game);

    tilskuertal(game, num_matches);

    char *team = "AAB";
    int goal = 2;

    uafgjorte_kampe_med_antal_maal(team, goal, game, num_matches);

    AAB_game(game, game_with_AAB, num_matches);

    return 0;
}

/* SELECT WHICH EXERCISE TO PRINT */
int main_interactive()
{
    int select, goal, k, i, l;
    char team[4];

    games game[MAX_LINE];
    games game_with_AAB[MAX_LINE];

    int num_matches = read_file(game);

    printf("\nPress 1 to get the number of spectators.\n");
    printf("\nPress 2 to get the matches ending with a draw.\n");
    printf("\nPress 3 to get the matches played by AAB.\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &select);

    switch(select)
    {
        case 1: tilskuertal(game, num_matches); break;

        case 2: printf("Enter the contraction of the team in uppercase letters: \n");
                scanf("%s", team);
                printf("Enter an even number representing the scores of the match: \n");
                scanf("%d", &goal);

                l = 1;
                for (i = 0; i < num_matches; ++i)
                {
                    k = strcmp(team, game[i].team_home);
                    if(k == 0)
                    {
                        l = k;
                    }
                }

                if(l == 0)
                {
                    if(goal % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        uafgjorte_kampe_med_antal_maal(team, goal, game, num_matches);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("The entered data is not valid.\n");
                    }
                } else{
                    printf("The entered data is not valid.\n");
                } break;

        case 3: AAB_game(game, game_with_AAB, num_matches);
                break;

        default : printf("This was not an option. \n");
    }

    return 0;
}

/* FUNCTIONS */

/* Reading external text-file */
int read_file(games *game)
{
  int a = 0, j, status;
  FILE *ipf = fopen("superliga-2014-2015.txt", "r");
  for(status = fscanf(ipf, "%d", &j); status != EOF; status = fscanf(ipf, "%d", &j))
  {
    fscanf(ipf, "%s %s %s %s - %s %d - %d %s",
    game[a].weekday, game[a].date,
    game[a].the_time, game[a].team_home,
    game[a].team_guest, &game[a].goal_home,
    &game[a].goal_guests, game[a].spectators1);
    a++;
  }


  fclose(ipf);

  return a;
}

/* EXERCISE 1: NUMBER OF SPECTATORS */
int tilskuertal(games *game, int num_matches)
{
    int tal_dele[3], i = 0, k;
    char *token;
    printf("\nExercise 1\n");

    while(i != num_matches)
    {
        tal_dele[2] = 0;
        k = 1;
        strcpy(game[i].spectators2, game[i].spectators1);
        char *s;
        s = strchr (game[i].spectators2, '.');
        if(s != NULL)
        {
            token = strtok(game[i].spectators2, ".");
            tal_dele[0] = atoi(token);

            while(token != NULL)
            {
                token = strtok(NULL, ".");
                tal_dele[k] = atoi(token);
                k++;
            }

            if (tal_dele[2] == 0)
            {
               game[i].tilskuere = (tal_dele[0] * 1000) + (tal_dele[1]);
            } else
            {
                game[i].tilskuere = (tal_dele[0] * 1000000) + (tal_dele[1] * 1000) + (tal_dele[2]);
            }

        } else
        {
           game[i].tilskuere = atoi(game[i].spectators1);

        }
        printf("There are: %d number of spectators\n", game[i].tilskuere);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* EXERCISE 2: DRAW MATCHES */
void uafgjorte_kampe_med_antal_maal(char *team, int goal, games *game, int num_matches)
{
    int k = 0, i, l, n;
    games draw[MAX_LINE];
    for (i = 0; i< num_matches; i++)
    {

        if (game[i].goal_home == game[i].goal_guests)
        {
            strcpy(draw[k].weekday, game[i].weekday);
            strcpy(draw[k].date, game[i].date);
            strcpy(draw[k].the_time, game[i].the_time);
            strcpy(draw[k].team_home, game[i].team_home);
            strcpy(draw[k].team_guest, game[i].team_guest);

            draw[k].goal_home = game[i].goal_home;
            draw[k].goal_guests = game[i].goal_guests;

            strcpy(draw[k].spectators1, game[i].spectators1);

            k++;
        }

    }
    printf("\n\nExercise 2\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        n = strcmp(team, draw[i].team_home);
        l = strcmp(team, draw[i].team_guest);
        if((draw[i].goal_home * 2 == goal) && ( n == 0|| l == 0))
        {

            printf("%3s   %5s %3s    %3s - %3s    %3d - %3d   %7s\n",
            draw[i].weekday, draw[i].date,
            draw[i].the_time, draw[i].team_home,
            draw[i].team_guest,
            draw[i].goal_home, draw[i].goal_guests,
            draw[i].spectators1);
        }
    }
}

/* EXERCISE 3: GAMES PLAYED BY AAB */
void AAB_game(games *game, games *game_with_AAB, int num_matches)
{
    printf("\n\nExercise 3\n");

    int i, k = 0, f, d;
    char *AAB;
    AAB = "AAB";
    for(i = 0; i < num_matches; i++)
    {

        d = strcmp(game[i].team_home, AAB);
        f = strcmp(game[i].team_guest, AAB);

        if(d == 0 || f == 0)
        {
            strcpy(game_with_AAB[k].weekday, game[i].weekday);
            strcpy(game_with_AAB[k].date, game[i].date);
            strcpy(game_with_AAB[k].the_time, game[i].the_time);
            strcpy(game_with_AAB[k].team_home, game[i].team_home);
            strcpy(game_with_AAB[k].team_guest, game[i].team_guest);
            game_with_AAB[k].goal_home = game[i].goal_home;
            game_with_AAB[k].goal_guests = game[i].goal_guests;
            strcpy(game_with_AAB[k].spectators1, game[i].spectators1);

            k++;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < k ; ++i)
    {
        f = strcmp(AAB, game_with_AAB[i].team_home);
        d = strcmp(AAB, game_with_AAB[i].team_guest);
        if(f == 0)
        {
            game_with_AAB[i].the_score = game_with_AAB[i].goal_home - game_with_AAB[i].goal_guests;
        }
        else if(d == 0)
        {
            game_with_AAB[i].the_score = game_with_AAB[i].goal_guests - game_with_AAB[i].goal_home;
        }
    }
        qsort(game_with_AAB, k, sizeof(games), comparing);

    for (i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        printf("%3s   %5s %3s    %3s - %3s    %3d - %3d   %7s\n",
        game_with_AAB[i].weekday, game_with_AAB[i].date,
        game_with_AAB[i].the_time, game_with_AAB[i].team_home,
        game_with_AAB[i].team_guest, game_with_AAB[i].goal_home,
        game_with_AAB[i].goal_guests, game_with_AAB[i].spectators1);
    }
}

int comparing(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    games *the_scoreA = (games *)a;
    games *the_scoreB = (games *)b;
    return (the_scoreB->the_score - the_scoreA->the_score);
}
```

Below is the text-file that I am reading from:

```
Fre     18/07 18.30     FCN - FCV       3 - 2      3.349
Lor     19/07 17.00     SDR - AAB       0 - 0      3.228   
Son     20/07 14.00     OB  - HOB       1 - 2      6.015   
Son     20/07 17.00     SIF - FCK       0 - 0      5.416   
Son     20/07 19.00     FCM - BIF       3 - 1      9.548   
Man     21/07 19.00     EFB - RFC       0 - 1      7.257   

Fre     25/07 18.30     FCV - OB        3 - 1      2.709  
Lor     26/07 17.00     AAB - FCM       2 - 0      7.543   
Lor     26/07 19.30     FCK - FCN       2 - 1     12.496  
Son     27/07 17.00     RFC - HOB       2 - 1      6.929   
Son     27/07 19.00     EFB - SDR       1 - 1      7.170   
Man     28/07 19.00     BIF - SIF       2 - 0     15.986  

Fre     01/08 18.30     SIF - SDR       0 - 2      3.105  
Lor     02/08 15.00     FCV - FCK       2 - 2      5.127   
Lor     02/08 17.00     OB  - AAB       1 - 1      5.840   
Son     03/08 17.00     FCN - EFB       3 - 2      3.146   
Son     03/08 19.00     HOB - BIF       2 - 0      6.583   
Man     04/08 19.00     FCM - RFC       3 - 1      6.937   

Fre     08/08 18.30     RFC - FCV       1 - 0      4.599  
Lor     09/08 17.00     AAB - FCN       1 - 2      5.904   
Son     10/08 14.00     SDR - FCM       1 - 3      4.119   
Son     10/08 17.00     FCK - HOB       0 - 3     14.664  
Son     10/08 19.00     BIF - OB        1 - 1     11.116  
Man     11/08 19.00     EFB - SIF       0 - 0      5.728   

Fre     15/08 19.30     FCK - FCM       1 - 2     13.106 
Lor     16/08 18.00     AAB - EFB       1 - 1      5.319   
Son     17/08 14.00     FCV - SIF       2 - 0      1.994   
Son     17/08 17.00     BIF - SDR       2 - 0      9.962   
Son     17/08 19.00     RFC - OB        0 - 2      3.952   
Man     18/08 19.00     HOB - FCN       0 - 0      4.221   

Lor     30/08 17.00     SDR - RFC       1 - 1      2.254  
Son     31/08 13.00     SIF - AAB       2 - 2      3.067   
Son     31/08 15.00     FCM - EFB       2 - 0      6.571   
Son     31/08 17.00     FCN - BIF       0 - 3      7.689   
Son     31/08 19.00     OB  - FCK       0 - 1      9.925   
Man     01/09 19.00     HOB - FCV       3 - 1      2.682   

Fre     12/09 18.30     FCM - OB        3 - 2      7.505  
Lor     13/09 20.35     AAB - FCK       1 - 0      8.546   
Son     14/09 14.00     SIF - FCN       1 - 2      2.390   
Son     14/09 17.00     BIF - RFC       0 - 2     25.551  
Son     14/09 19.00     EFB - FCV       3 - 0      5.209   
Man     15/09 19.00     SDR - HOB       1 - 1      4.138   

Fre     19/09 18.30     RFC - SIF       1 - 0      5.126  
Lor     20/09 17.00     HOB - EFB       1 - 1      3.736   
Son     21/09 14.00     OB  - SDR       1 - 1      7.201   
Son     21/09 16.30     FCK - BIF       1 - 0     32.526  
Son     21/09 19.00     FCN - FCM       2 - 1      4.637   
Man     22/09 19.00     FCV - AAB       1 - 0      2.703   

Fre     26/09 18.30     AAB - RFC       0 - 0      5.357  
Lor     27/09 15.00     SDR - FCK       1 - 1      5.535   
Lor     27/09 17.00     SIF - HOB       2 - 2      3.081   
Son     28/09 14.00     FCM - FCV       1 - 0      6.669   
Son     28/09 19.00     EFB - BIF       2 - 2     10.650  
Man     29/09 19.00     FCN - OB        2 - 1      4.425   

Fre     03/10 18.30     HOB - FCM       1 - 5      4.968  
Lor     04/10 17.00     OB  - SIF       2 - 0      5.587   
Son     05/10 13.00     FCV - SDR       1 - 1      2.677   
Son     05/10 15.00     RFC - FCN       0 - 0      5.021   
Son     05/10 17.00     FCK - EFB       2 - 1     15.236  
Son     05/10 19.00     BIF - AAB       2 - 1     15.412  

Fre     17/10 18.30     AAB - HOB       1 - 1      9.923  
Lor     18/10 17.00     FCN - SDR       2 - 3      3.512   
Son     19/10 14.00     FCM - SIF       2 - 1      8.622    
Son     19/10 17.00     BIF - FCV       5 - 0     12.190  
Son     19/10 19.00     FCK - RFC       1 - 0     10.723  
Man     20/10 19.00     EFB - OB        2 - 0      6.478   

Fre     24/10 18.30     SIF - FCV       1 - 2      2.160  
Lor     25/10 17.00     SDR - FCM       1 - 1      4.174   
Son     26/10 14.00     RFC - OB        3 - 0      5.135   
Son     26/10 17.00     HOB - FCK       0 - 2      4.738   
Son     26/10 19.00     EFB - BIF       0 - 0     10.077  
Man     27/10 19.00     FCN - AAB       0 - 1      4.016   

Fre     31/10 18.30     FCM - FCN       2 - 0      6.543  
Lor     01/11 17.00     FCV - EFB       1 - 4      2.602   
Son     02/11 14.00     OB  - HOB       3 - 1      8.011   
Son     02/11 17.00     FCK - SDR       1 - 1     21.413  
Son     02/11 18.30     BIF - RFC       1 - 0      12.497  
Man     03/11 19.00     AAB - SIF       2 - 0      6.240   

Fre     07/11 18.30     SIF - FCM       1 - 2      3.587  
Lor     08/11 19.00     RFC - EFB       3 - 2      3.929   
Son     09/11 13.00     SDR - OB        2 - 1      4.428   
Son     09/11 15.00     AAB - FCV       2 - 0      6.369   
Son     09/11 17.00     HOB - BIF       3 - 0      4.389   
Son     09/11 19.15     FCN - FCK       0 - 0      4.567   

Fre     21/11 18.30     FCV - RFC       0 - 1      1.849  
Lor     22/11 17.00     EFB - HOB       4 - 2      6.057   
Lor     22/11 19.30     FCK - SIF       1 - 0      8.456   
Son     23/11 14.00     OB  - FCN       1 - 0      5.927   
Son     23/11 17.00     BIF - SDR       1 - 0     12.647  
Son     23/11 19.00     FCM - AAB       2 - 0      8.005   

Fre     28/11 18.30     SDR - EFB       0 - 0      2.609  
Lor     29/11 17.00     SIF - OB        0 - 1      1.866   
Son     30/11 14.00     HOB - RFC       0 - 1      3.884   
Son     30/11 17.00     FCN - BIF       2 - 0      5.168   
Son     30/11 19.00     AAB - FCK       0 - 1      7.437   
Man     01/12 19.00     FCM - FCV       2 - 1      6.778   

Fre     05/12 18.30     RFC - SDR       0 - 0      4.551  
Lor     06/12 17.00     OB  - AAB       1 - 1      5.025   
Son     07/12 14.00     FCV - HOB       1 - 1      2.377   
Son     07/12 17.00     BIF - SIF       1 - 0     19.304  
Son     07/12 19.00     FCK - FCM       3 - 0     17.499  
Man     08/12 19.00     EFB - FCN       0 - 0      5.150   

Fre     20/02 18.30     FCN - RFC       0 - 3      3.316  
Lor     21/02 17.00     SIF - EFB       1 - 3      2.247   
Son     22/02 14.00     SDR - HOB       1 - 0      3.812   
Son     22/02 17.00     FCK - FCV       2 - 0     12.631  
Son     22/02 19.00     AAB - BIF       1 - 0      7.857   
Man     23/02 19.00     FCM - OB        3 - 0      7.602   

Fre     27/02 18.30     FCV - SDR       0 - 1      1.750  
Lor     28/02 17.00     HOB - FCN       1 - 0      2.086   
Son     01/03 14.00     RFC - SIF       1 - 2      4.263   
Son     01/03 17.00     OB  - FCK       1 - 0      8.421   
Son     01/03 19.00     BIF - FCM       1 - 1     13.092  
Man     02/03 19.00     EFB - AAB       1 - 3      5.260   

Lor     07/03 17.00     FCN - SDR       4 - 0      2.389  
Son     08/03 13.00     SIF - HOB       0 - 1      2.620   
Son     08/03 15.00     FCK - BIF       3 - 1     31.223  
Son     08/03 17.00     FCM - EFB       3 - 0      9.190   
Son     08/03 19.00     AAB - RFC       2 - 1      5.670   
Man     09/03 19.00     FCV - OB        1 - 2      2.134   

Fre     13/03 18.30     RFC - FCM       1 - 2      5.463  
Lor     14/03 17.00     SDR - SIF       1 - 4      3.145   
Son     15/03 14.00     FCN - FCV       2 - 0      3.243   
Son     15/03 17.00     EFB - FCK       0 - 1      7.716   
Son     15/03 19.00     BIF - OB        2 - 0     12.791  
Man     16/03 19.00     HOB - AAB       1 - 0      6.596   

Fre     20/03 18.30     OB  - EFB       0 - 2      6.005  
Lor     21/03 17.00     FCM - HOB       3 - 0      9.202   
Son     22/03 13.00     SIF - FCN       2 - 2      1.814   
Son     22/03 15.00     AAB - SDR       1 - 4      4.644   
Son     22/03 17.00     FCV - BIF       0 - 1      4.242   
Son     22/03 19.00     FCK - RFC       1 - 1      9.520   

Lor     04/04 17.00     SDR - FCN       1 - 2      2.375  
Son     05/04 17.00     HOB - SIF       2 - 2      2.940   
Son     05/04 19.00     EFB - FCM       3 - 3      7.682   
Man     06/04 16.00     BIF - FCK       0 - 0     22.020  
Man     06/04 19.30     RFC - AAB       1 - 1      5.083   
Tir     07/04 19.00     OB  - FCV       1 - 2      4.331   

Fre     10/04 18.30     HOB - EFB       3 - 1      2.743  
Lor     11/04 17.00     RFC - FCV       1 - 1      4.557   
Son     12/04 14.00     FCN - OB        1 - 2      5.264   
Son     12/04 17.00     AAB - FCM       1 - 2      7.690   
Son     12/04 19.00     SDR - BIF       0 - 1      4.633   
Man     13/04 19.00     SIF - FCK       0 - 4      3.578   

Fre     17/04 18.30     FCM - SIF       1 - 0      9.058  
Lor     18/04 15.00     FCV - AAB       2 - 1      1.854   
Son     19/04 14.00     OB  - SDR       0 - 0      6.644   
Son     19/04 17.00     BIF - HOB       0 - 1     15.904  
Son     19/04 19.30     FCK - FCN       2 - 0     10.944  
Man     20/04 19.00     EFB - RFC       0 - 0      5.690   

Fre     24/04 18.30     EFB - OB        0 - 2      5.402  
Lor     25/04 17.00     FCN - SIF       1 - 0      3.883   
Son     26/04 14.00     SDR - AAB       0 - 3      3.615   
Son     26/04 17.00     BIF - FCV       4 - 0     12.014  
Son     26/04 19.00     RFC - FCK       3 - 0      5.777   
Man     27/04 19.00     HOB - FCM       0 - 0      4.166   

Fre     01/05 18.30     AAB - HOB       5 - 0      9.401  
Lor     02/05 17.00     SIF - SDR       2 - 2      1.965   
Son     03/05 14.00     FCV - FCN       2 - 1      1.688   
Son     03/05 17.00     FCK - EFB       2 - 1     12.892  
Son     03/05 19.00     OB  - BIF       0 - 2      9.605   
Man     04/05 19.00     FCM - RFC       5 - 2      9.039   

Fre     08/05 18.30     RFC - FCN       2 - 0      5.930  
Lor     09/05 17.00     EFB - SIF       5 - 2      6.741   
Son     10/05 14.00     HOB - SDR       2 - 2      2.787   
Son     10/05 17.00     OB  - FCM       3 - 1      6.378   
Son     10/05 19.00     BIF - AAB       1 - 1     14.061  
Man     11/05 19.00     FCV - FCK       0 - 1      3.544   

Fre     15/05 18.30     AAB - OB        0 - 2      7.506  
Son     17/05 14.00     HOB - FCV       0 - 1      2.082   
Son     17/05 17.00     SIF - BIF       0 - 2      3.996   
Son     17/05 19.00     FCM - FCK       2 - 0     11.305  
Man     18/05 18.00     FCN - EFB       1 - 3      3.019   
Man     18/05 20.15     SDR - RFC       1 - 1      2.524   

Ons     20/05 18.00     OB  - SIF       1 - 1      4.717  
Ons     20/05 20.00     FCK - AAB       1 - 0      8.127   
Tor     21/05 18.00     RFC - HOB       0 - 1      6.499   
Tor     21/05 18.00     FCV - FCM       0 - 0      2.432   
Tor     21/05 20.00     BIF - FCN       3 - 1     10.052  
Tor     21/05 20.00     EFB - SDR       2 - 3      6.060   

Son     24/05 17.00     SDR - FCV       1 - 1      5.075  
Man     25/05 13.00     FCN - HOB       4 - 2      3.392   
Man     25/05 15.00     SIF - RFC       0 - 2      2.052   
Man     25/05 17.00     FCK - OB        1 - 0     14.463  
Man     25/05 19.00     FCM - BIF       2 - 3     11.535  
Tir     26/05 19.00     AAB - EFB       1 - 0      4.793   

Son     31/05 16.00     EFB - FCV       2 - 1     10.702 
Son     31/05 16.00     RFC - BIF       1 - 1      9.143   
Son     31/05 16.00     HOB - OB        2 - 2      2.958   
Son     31/05 16.00     SDR - FCK       1 - 2      5.643   
Son     31/05 16.00     FCN - FCM       1 - 0      4.408   
Son     31/05 16.00     SIF - AAB       1 - 2      2.103   

Son     07/06 16.00     OB  - RFC       0 - 2      7.000  
Son     07/06 16.00     BIF - EFB       0 - 1     22.838  
Son     07/06 16.00     AAB - FCN       1 - 0      6.776   
Son     07/06 16.00     FCM - SDR       2 - 1     11.535  
Son     07/06 16.00     FCK - HOB       1 - 0     16.699  
Son     07/06 16.00     FCV - SIF       3 - 1      1.201
```

Comment: You posted a lot of code. Could you make a [mcve] and cut down the code to just enough to reproduce the crash?

Comment: Did you run the program in a debugger? Compile with `address-sanitizer`? Run under `valgrind`? Have you tried narrowing the problem down? Run under `catchsegv`? Does the segfault message mention an instruction pointer? Dump core?

Comment: I can try. Just a second.

Comment: Another way to phrase @EOF's comment is: What debugging have you done on your own already and what have you found out? (Note: Posting on SO should not be considered a primary debugging technique despite what many people seem to think).

Comment: Honestly, I have not tried any debugger as I am not familiar with using a debugger yet. I am not posting here as a method of debugging. I like to learn, but I simply cannot figure this one out.. I've tried some time now..

Comment: @Kentah: Well, what platform are you working on? Windows? *BSD? OSX? Linux? What compiler/toolchain do you use? SunCC? ICC? clang? gcc?

Comment: @Kentah " I have not tried any debugger as I am not familiar with using a debugger yet". Looks if it's time to start now.

Comment: At the very least: compile with `-g`, then run `gdb --args ./yourprogram a b c d` (after --args put however you'd normally run your program) then type `run`, then when it crashes use `bt` to see where it crashed, and `quit` to exit gdb.

Comment: The `for (status = fscanf(ipf, "%d", &j); status != EOF; status = fscanf(ipf, "%d", &j))` in your `read_file` function is very peculiar. There's no integer at the beginning of each line, so it looks like you're using a  `fscanf` call for a type you don't expect in order to determine when you hit the end of file. This isn't the cause of your segfault, but it's very odd.

Answer (score 1):

in function: `tilskuertal()`, the nested while() loops have sequencing problems.

Only use the returned value from a call to `strtok()`  after checking that the value is not NULL.

The code is using the value before checking.

I.E. place the call to `strtok()` last in a while loop and once before entering the while() loop.

here is example code:

```
for( i=0; i<num_matches; i++ )
{
    tal_dele[2] = 0;
    k = 0; // start with 0 for in index into tal_dele[]
    if( !strcpy(game[i].spectators2, game[i].spectators1) )
    { // strcpy() failed
        perror( "strcpy failed" );
        continue;
    }

    token = strtok(game[i].spectators2, ".");
    for( k =0; (k < 3 && token); k++ )
    {
        tal_dele[k] = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ".");
    }
    ....
}
```

in function: read_file():

1. when calling `fopen()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

suggest:

```
FILE *ifp = NULL;
if( NULL == (ifp = fopen( "superliga-2014-2015.txt", "r") ) )
{ // the fopen failed
    perror( "fopen to read: superliga-2014-2015.txt failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, fopen successful
```

Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are found in header file: stdlib.h

2. when calling `fscanf()` always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  The returned value should equal the number of format specifiers.  Otherwise an error occurred.
3. when scanning a '%s' format specifier, always use a 'length' modifier (that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer) so the input buffer cannot be overflowed, resulting in undefined behaviour and leading to a seg fault event..
4. the `for()` is trying to input two `int` fields (both of which will fail) Strongly suggest eliminating that call to `fscanf()` and placing the `fscanf()` for the game data as the control for the `while()` loop. and check for a returned value of 8.  Any other value means an error or EOF or signal occurred and it is time to get out of the loop.
5. the posted code has no limit on how many lines are read from the input file.

suggest:

```
while( (a < MAX_GAMES) 
&& 
8 == fscanf(ipf, "%s %s %s %s - %s %d - %d %s",
           game[a].weekday, game[a].date,
           game[a].the_time, game[a].team_home,
           game[a].team_guest, &game[a].goal_home,
           &game[a].goal_guests, game[a].spectators1) ) {
```

in function: `main_interactive()`

6. the field `team` will contain a NUL terminated string so the max data is 3 characters.

so this line:

```
scanf("%s", team);
```

needs a length modifier to avoid the user overflowing the input buffer.  suggest:

```
scanf("%3s", team);
```

7. for ease of readability and understanding, please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*